# Не могу сделать поиск alt+<key>: windows, ssh putty, Midnight Commander

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, mc

Захожу на linux машину по ssh через putty с windows, на машине есть mc. 
Вот только что надо поменять в настройках putty чтоб корректно mc реагировал на нажатия alt? Вроде по alt+? должен появится диалог поиска.

везде стоит xterm, и в putty и echo $TEMP

Comment: Это(?): Ctrl+s, Esc+Shift+?

Comment: @defrag, а что это? потыкал - ничего не произошло.

Comment: Это и есть хоткеи для диалогов поиска в mc.

Comment: @defrag, вот такого окна я не получил http://pingvinus.ru/files/notes/search-text-in-linux-mc/mc-text-search.png говорят, надо alt+? тыкать

Comment: Вот тут https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/ru/doc/filePanels/hotkeys говорят, что надо тыкать Meta+Shift+? (где Meta - это либо Alt, либо Esc)

Comment: @defrag спасибо! alt+shift+? - то что надо!

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - перейти на связку [far2l](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l) + [putty4far2l](https://github.com/unxed/putty4far2l) (мой форк putty). Все привычные горячие клавиши классического двухпанельника заработают. Если mc запускать в far2l в putty4far2l, тоже все хоткеи работать будут. В качестве бонуса получите работающий через ssh буфер обмена :)

Comment: Это не решает вопрос с Midnight Commander. См. обсуждение «[**Уход от проблемы вместо её решения**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3404/199934)». Спасибо.